# additional cookies are generated automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, cookies, next.js

Am working a next js project and used react-cookie npm package, am using cookies for managing session. In which, am creating cookie as "token" as key name and token value for cookie value.

I found an issue related to cookies. Sometimes multiple cookies are generated while login
cookie generated as -> authenticated cookie value as cookie key and "true" as its cookie value. And may be due to this reason while accessing site am getting

400 bad request - request header or cookie too large

I have checked my code where am setting cookies but am only creating cookie as token and its value. And I have called backend apis using fetch request.

```
    setCookie("token", user.token, {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 86400, 
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about cookies expiring. The website suspects you might be a bot, so it's giving you a puzzle to solve. you can learn more about reCAPTCHA [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).